# Java BMICalculator does not work as expected

Tags: java

I am learning to code in Java and I cannot figure out why this won't work. I will add screenshots It keeps returning NaN I think this means: not a number ... but it is a number? The Screenshots:[Java code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9Hu7.png) and [What it returns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ped4.png)

Comment: Please do not post code as images.

Comment: I will copy and paste it next time instead, but using screenshots is easier. (-_-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your program , you are calculating BMI way before expecting user input. Hence you are getting that output, i.e. you are calculating BMI for 0 value.

The actual way is calculate BMI i.e. execute BMI statement after accepting user input values.

Answer (score 1):

- At the beginning the value of `hm = 0` after evaluating `line 6 ,7 and 8`
- Later when you use `hm` to calculate `BMI` you are doing a divide by 0 (because `hm = 0`), which results in `BMI = NaN` which java [uses](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#NaN) to refer to (+)(-)infinity or indeterminate type of results.
- Later you think that you're calculating the `BMI` by assigning values to `hm` and `hf` but no,  you're just assigning values them and nothing else and then you just print it which results in whatever is in`BMI` being printed which is `NaN`

I'd advise you to go through an introductory programming  course.

Answer (score 0):

place the following statements

```
double hm = (hm*12 + hi)/39.37;
double wkg = wp/2.205;
double BMI = wkg/(hm*hm);
```

after the statement

```
wp = keyboard.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

Java is a programming language **without lazy evaluation**, so you shouldn't write "how the value are calculated" before they are assigned with the real value.

You are just allowed to assign value then calculate them.